# jQuery, issue with removeClass

Tags: jquery, opacity, removeclass, mouseenter

I have the css:

```
.frame{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:3px;
}

.test2{
    opacity:0;
}
```

and I have the html

```
<div class="frame">
<span class="test test2">qwerty</span>
</div>
```

When the mouse is over .frame I want to remove the class .test2 to .test, and when the mouse is leave.frame I want to add .test2 to .test.
So my jQuery code is:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.frame', function( e ) {
    var $el=$(this),
    mEnt  = e.type == "mouseenter";
    if(mEnt == true){
        el.find('.test').removeClass('test2');
    }else{
        el.find('.test').addClass('test2');
    }
});
```

But it doesn't work, .test2 doesn't want to remove from .test.
here a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/EmE7p/

Comment: simply checking the console could've saved you the time of asking this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot a `$` in `el`, should be `$el`

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.frame', function (e) {
    var $el = $(this),
        mEnt = e.type == "mouseenter";
    if (mEnt == true) {
        $el.find('.test').removeClass('test2');
    } else {
        $el.find('.test').addClass('test2');
    }
});
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/htbzu/)**

The best solution for this can be plain **CSS** (and no jQuery needed), like this:

```
.test {
    opacity:0;
}
.frame:hover .test {
    opacity:1;
}
```

**Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/htbzu/1/)**

Answer (score 2):

First: Unless you need to support IE7 and earier, this is a case where you really should just use `:hover` in your CSS:

```
.frame{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:3px;
}

.frame .test {
    opacity: 0;
}

.frame:hover .test {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But if you want to do it in JavaScript, the problem with the code is that you're using `$el` for the element in one place, but `el` in other places. You need to be consistent. You should have been seeing errors in the JavaScript console. You also don't need the `mEnt` variable, nor do you need to use `== true` when testing conditions.

So:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.frame', function( e ) {
    var $el=$(this);
    if(e.type == "mouseenter"){
        $el.find('.test').removeClass('test2');
    }else{
        $el.find('.test').addClass('test2');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable is `$el` but the `removeClass` method is being called on `el`.

```
$(document).on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.frame', function( e ) {
    var $el=$(this),
    mEnt  = e.type == "mouseenter";
    if(mEnt == true){
        $el.find('.test').removeClass('test2');
    }else{
        $el.find('.test').addClass('test2');
    }
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/EmE7p/3/

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```
$(".frame").hover(
  function () {
    //here mouse enter
  },
  function () {
    //here mouse leave
  }
);
```